# How to logoff a user when the workstation is locked?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, usersession

I wrote a Windows application that comes with two modules: service and user-mode applications. The service implements its own scheduler and may log-off a user at a predefined time. For that I was using the following call that is triggered from my user-mode module running in a logged-on user session that has to be logged off:

```
BOOL result = ExitWindowsEx(EWX_LOGOFF, reason);
```

This works fine, except of the situation when a user's account is locked. In that case that API doesn't seem to do anything at all even through I get 1 returned from it.

So I was curious, is there any other way to log off a user when their account is locked? (One condition I have in this case is that if that user had any unsaved documents then the log-off should not be forced.)

Comment: In which version of Windows ?

Comment: @Xearinox: XP through 8.1

Comment: Have you tried WTSLogoffSession?  (It isn't clear from the documentation whether this forces a log-off when there are unsaved documents or not.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Yes, it forces the logoff even in despite of unsaved documents.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
DWORD dFlags = EWX_LOGOFF | EWX_FORCE | 0x10200;

BOOL result = ExitWindowsEx(dFlags, reason);
```

Comment: `0x10200` is some extra flag? Something undocumented?

Comment: @Mario: Good point. Also, as I said in my original question I can't use `EWX_FORCE` ... unless `0x10200` does something to it. So, user2120666, please explain yourself.